# Public Variables Not Being Read When Running One Method From Another

Tags: java

This is not my actual code, but it shows what I want to do. Why does the Print method end up printing the original value instead of the updated one when run inside another method? When I run them both from PSVM, it prints the number 3 like I expected it to.

```
  public int testOne = 0;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main tester = new Main();
    tester.Increase();
  }
  public void Increase() {
    Main tester = new Main();
    testOne = 3;
    tester.Print();
  }
  public void Print() {
    System.out.println(testOne);
  }
}
```

Output seems to come out as 0, anyone know why this happens? Running it in repl.it if it is a compiler thing.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Main` inside `Increase`? Did you mean to use `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Increase() {
  Main tester = new Main(); // new instance Main1, testOne = 0
  testOne = 3; // current instance Main0, testOne = 3
  tester.Print(); // calling Main1.Print() prints 0
}
```

The testOne assignment you do is the one in the current class, but you're actually calling the Print() function from a completely new instance of the class you created in the local scope.
What you want to do is this:

```
public void Increase() {
  testOne = 3;
  Print();
}
```

This Print() method will be called from the current class context.

The problem you're facing is scope. Read up on it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of your class, so therefore two testOne variables, but you're only printing one of them

Either you need to set the instance variable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main tester = new Main();
    tester.Increase();
    // tester.Print(); // would print 0
  }
  public void Increase() {
    Main tester = new Main();
    tester.testOne = 3;
    tester.Print();
 }
 public void Print() {
  System.out.println(testOne);  // prints 3
 }
```

Or don't make another instance at all

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main tester = new Main();
  tester.Increase();
}
public void Increase() {
  this.testOne = 3;
  this.Print();
}
public void Print() {
  System.out.println(testOne);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be using Static.

```
public static int testOne = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main tester = new Main();
    tester.Increase();
}

public void Increase() {
    Main tester = new Main();
    testOne = 3;
    tester.Print();
}

public void Print() {
    System.out.println(testOne);
}
```